# Firestore, retrieve specific fields as JSON?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve specific fields from a given firestore collection (inside of an HTTPSCallable) but I'm getting "nulls" for fields that I know exist and have data. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
var docs;
        await db
          .collection(mycollection)
          .where("flag", "==", "true")
          .get()
          .then((querySnapshot) => {
            docs = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
              doc.data();
            });
          });
        return JSON.stringify({ mydocs: docs });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using promise chaining and async-await at the same time. The return statement will execute without checking if the promise returned by Firestore is resolved. Try this:

```
const querySnapshot = await db
          .collection(mycollection)
          .where("flag", "==", "true")
          .get()

const docs = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());

return JSON.stringify({ mydocs: docs });
```

If you are using promise chaining then anything that should happen after the promise is resolved should ideally be inside of the `then()` block:

```
const myQuery = db.collection(mycollection).where("flag", "==", "true")
return myQuery.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  const docs = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());

  return JSON.stringify({ mydocs: docs });
})
```